# How to store a value from firestore in a variable in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get a value in firestore and save in a local variable. I can print that value but I couldn't save that value in a variable. the following code give me null value for that variable.

```
_onPressed() async {
  String userType;
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  firestoreInstance
      .collection("users")
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    userType = document['userType'];
  });
  print(userType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DocumentSnapshot` is not itself the data. You can extract the data from it by using `data` getter on it. So you can try getting the `userType` like this..

```
_onPressed() async {
  String userType;
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  firestoreInstance
      .collection("users")
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
          var document = snapshot.data;
          userType = document['userType'];
      });
  print(userType);
}
```

Outside of the curly brackets of the `then` block, you still get it `null` because the code block inside the `then` curly brackets is executed after the `get()` future resolves. While that future is still processing, the `print(userType)` is already executed and so it is null at that time. To wait for the processing you will need to `await` the `get()` call too like this..

```
_onPressed() async {
  String userType;
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get();
      
  var document = snapshot.data;
  userType = document['userType'];

  print(userType);
}
```

Comment: it's working after I changed "getData" as "data", and it's giving null when we print usertype after closing that

Comment: did you make sure that the document in fact has a field named `userType`?

Comment: Yeah I can sure, because I can print that value inside curly braces, but I can't print after that.

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, the `userType` is only available inside the `then` block.

If you want to have it available outside of that, you can use `await` instead of `then`, similar to what you already do when calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`.

Something like:

```
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  var document = await firestoreInstance
      .collection("users")
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .get();
  userType = document['userType'];
  print(userType);
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked,  Can you please tell me how can I use this "userType" variable in other place, how can I do that?

Comment: If you call `_onPressed()` from other places, make sure to `await _onPressed()`